# Ejecutar archivo js desde mi vista pasándole un parámetro

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc, vistas

En curso reciente, el profesor nos dejó ejemplo de cómo ejecutar el paginado de nuestras vistas, lo hizo mediante una función en un archivo js (en mi caso inventario.js) y con apoyo de un script jquery.bootpag.min.js que se referencia en la vista, he replicado lo mismo en mi proyecto y funciona bien. Lo que intento hacer es pasarle a ese archivo inventario.js, el valor de un input text para ejecutar filtros en mi vista. Este es el archivo inventario.js:

```
(function (inventario) {

    inventario.success = successReload;
    inventario.pages = 1;
    inventario.rowSize = 25;
    init();
    return inventario;
    function successReload(option) {
        soporte.closeModal(option);
    }

    function init() {
        $.get('/Inventario/Count/' + inventario.rowSize,
            function (data) {
                inventario.pages = data;
                $('.pagination').bootpag({
                    total: inventario.pages,
                    page: 1,
                    maxVisible: 10,
                    leaps: true,
                    firstLastUse: true,
                    first: '←',
                    last: '→',
                    wrapClass: 'pagination',
                    activeClass: 'active',
                    disabledClass: 'disabled',
                    nextClass: 'next',
                    prevClass: 'prev',
                    lastClass: 'last',
                    firstClass: 'first'
                }).on('page', function (event, num) {
                    getInventarios(num);
                });
                getInventarios(1);
            });
    }
    function getInventarios(num) {

        var filtro = "sist";
        var url = '/inventario/List/' + num + '/' + inventario.rowSize + '/' + filtro;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('.content').html(data);
        });
    }
})(window.inventario = window.inventario || {});
```

Para probar agregué la variable filtro y comprobé que funciona, hace el filtro, pero la idea es ejecutar nuevamente el archivo inventario.js pasándole el valor de esa variable filtro.
En la vista el archivo inventario.js es referenciado así:

Y el código del input text es el siguiente:

```
<span class="col-md-3 text-right">
    Búsqueda General
    <input id="Filtro" name="Filtro" type="text" style="width: 240px; height: 30px" value="" />
</span>
```

Y en el controlador el código siguiente:

```
    [Route("Inventario/List/{pagina:int}/{filas:int}/{filtro}")]
    public PartialViewResult List(int pagina, int filas, string filtro)
    {
        if (pagina <= 0 || filas <= 0) return PartialView(new List<InventarioList>());
        var RegistroInicio = ((pagina - 1) * filas) + 1;
        var RegistroFinal = pagina * filas;
        //string filtro = "";
        return PartialView("_List", _unit.InventarioList.PagedList(RegistroInicio, RegistroFinal, filtro));
    }
```

En mi vista he agregado el siguiente siguiente script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let $comment = document.getElementById("Filtro")
    $comment.addEventListener('change', () => {
        var filtro = $("#Filtro").val();
        alert(filtro);
    })
</script>
```

Con este script capturo lo escrito en el input text (he comprobado que funciona), sólo me falta cómo hacer para desde ese script ejecutar el archivo inventario.js pasándole el filtro como parámetro.

Gracias por su atención

Comment: Ese `init` ¿está dentro de un `.cshtml` ?

Comment: Está dentro del archivo inventario.js

Comment: El archivo inventario.js está dentro de la carpeta App

Comment: Asegúrate que la ruta sea una ruta absoluta -> `$.get('/Inventario/Count/' + inventario.rowSize,` => `$.get('https://dominio .com/Inventario/Count/' + inventario.rowSize,`